# What is the right way of adding code examples for non-go code in go comments?

Tags: go

I have a golang function that reads a yaml file. It expects the the file to have a specific format (a specific set of keys):

```
// LoadFromYAML reads a yaml file of the form:
//
//   name: The Farm
//   tags:
//     - low_performing
//     - needs_attention
//   animals:
//     indoor:
//       cat: 2
//       dog: 3
//     outdoor:
//       horse: 1
//       pig: 1
//
// and does something with it
func LoadFromYAML(filename string) err {
  // ...
}
```

When I run `gofmt` on the file it changes the indentation of the example yaml contents:

```
➜  tmp gofmt t.go > t2.go && diff t.go t2.go
5,16c5,16
< //   # Not a real farm
< //   name: The Farm
< //   tags:
< //       - performance.low
< //       - needs_attention
< //   animals:
< //       indoor:
< //           cat: 2
< //           dog: 3
< //       outdoor:
< //           horse: 1
< //           pig: 1
---
> //    # Not a real farm
> //    name: The Farm
> //    tags:
> //        - performance.low
> //        - needs_attention
> //    animals:
> //        indoor:
> //            cat: 2
> //            dog: 3
> //        outdoor:
> //            horse: 1
> //            pig: 1
```

In particular, it changed spaces for tabs (which is not reflected in the copy pasted output here) which makes the example now contain invalid `yaml`.

I think this is because in go comments are assumed to have some structure as described [here](https://go.dev/doc/comment). What is the right way to put code samples that have their own formatting rules in comments?

Comment: `gofmt -s filename.go`

Comment: After some searching, it seems impossible to make fmt ignore comments. As usual, it's the Google-way or the highway.

Comment: what if you only paste code which already has no tabs ?  ...  first replace tabs with spaces then paste that code

Comment: `go doc LoadFromYAML` prints spaces, not tabs. When rendering HTML, no prefix is added at all. So I don't really see the problem.

Comment: I mean I understand that there are workarounds. But normally I dont step out of my editor (vim) to copy/paste codes from other parts of the codebase.